# Disable error reporting while installing application in php

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm developing a web application in php that requires a MySQL Database.

On every request i will check if the application is installed, following this workflow:

1. call main configuration file;
2. the main config file checks if custom config file exists (this file contains user defined DB connection data);
3. if custom config exists, call installation config file (to define installation point);
4. install config calls db class and try to connect;
5. if connected checks tables with sql statement "SHOW TABLES".
   ...

My question is in 4., if it is a bad practice to set report_errors(0) while trying to connect, because i don't want to show the connection errors to the user, i will only inform the user that the data on custom config is not correct.

After trying to connect i redefine the error reporting to E_ALL | E_STRICT.

Btw, I'm also open to critics to the entire process.

Thank you.

Comment: offtopic: why there is no tag in stack overflow for "best-practices"?

Comment: Usually, you'd wanna see the error logs during the development; show nothing in production, but append errors in a log file.

Comment: Or you could migrate to an exception model. Catch any errors that are issued during the configuration step and deal with them appropriately.

Comment: Yes, i have an error handler class for it combined with a debugger to display them if active (while dev). I really should use it to not show the error, and i could catch it to be more specific to the user about what he did wrong on the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use this code

```
<?php
    $old_value = error_reporting(0);
    /*Lets install the application here!*/

    /*Application is done installing, lets put error reporting back to normal!*/
    error_reporting($old_value);
?>
```

Comment: Yep, this is what i thought to do, disable at the beginning and enable when installed.